# Way to remove a string of unspecific characters from a string

Tags: python

I am trying to transform an inputting string based on markers.

So, `("Hail Mary #Run quick see\ncd!sawce", ["#", "!"])` would remove all characters after the markers, but until a backslash or the strings end.

That case would become `("Hail Mary #Run quick see\ncd!sawce", ["#", "!"])`

> > `Hail Mary
> >     cd`

I have written this:

```
def solution(string, markers):
    orig = string.strip()
    wholeList = []
    newString = orig
    for char in orig:
        for j in markers:
            if char == j:
                i = orig.index(char)
                newString = orig[:i].strip()
                wholeList.append(newString)
        if char == "\\":
            i = orig.index(char)
            orig = orig[i:]

return "".join(wholeList)
```

Comment: This is simple to do with regular expressions.

Comment: Why does it keep `\ncd`? There's no backslash there, that's a newline character.

Comment: Why was the space *before* the `#` not included in the output?

Comment: @trincot No, I stripped the white space from the first string segment

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it keeps \ncd still inside of the final string

Comment: But there's no backslash in the string. The backslash is part of an escape sequence that creates a newline character in the string.

Comment: How can I refer to the newline character in this case?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to escape your backslash if you intend to have a literal backslash in your string literal.

You can then use a regular expression substitution:

```
import re
s = "Hail Thor #Run quick see\\ncd!sawce"
print( re.sub( r"[#!].*?(?=[\\]|$)", "", s) )   # Hail Thor \ncd
```

If you intended to have a newline `\n`, and you want the removal to go until the next newline character, then it is even easier, as by default `.` does not match with a newline:

```
import re
s = "Hail Thor #Run quick see\ncd!sawce"
print( re.sub( r"[#!].*", "", s) )   # Hail Thor
                                     # cd
```

Comment: Or use a raw string.

Comment: Indeed, that would also work: `r"Hail Thor #Run quick see\ncd!sawce"`.

Comment: In this problem I don't want to change the input. If the user inputs a newline character then I want to include the characters after that element.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so there is no change of the input happening in my answer. `sub` does not change `s`, but returns a new string that has the result. I added an alternative, since your mention of *"... until a backslash..."* is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

While I'll agree with @trincot to use regex, I made an alternative solution:

```
def solution(text, markers):
    # If all the markers are used or
    # there are no markers return text
    if len(markers) < 1:
        return text.strip()
    else:
        # Get the first marker
        marker = markers.pop(0)
        # Split the string with the marker
        before, after = text.split(marker)
        # Split the remaining string at a newline
        after = after.split("\n", 1)
        if len(after) > 1:
            end = "\n" + after[-1]
        else:
            end = ""
        text = before.strip() + end
        return solution(text, markers)
```